# Why is the Restrict function not working properly?

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

```
eoy=date(date.today().year, 12, 31)
eoy=eoy.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
begin = '07/06/2020' 

appts = appts.Restrict("[Start] >= '" +begin+ "' AND [Start] <= '" +eoy+ "'")
```

[image]

Why am I getting 2019 date result? Thanks for your help

Comment: Different data types?  Or it is doing a string comparison instead of a date comparison.

Comment: the restrict function only allows String comparison and I am using this code https://medium.com/@ajaxus_68/automating-outlook-calendar-downloads-with-python-5fb3671b56a

Comment: Is that a recurring appointment?

Comment: Is the start column type a string or date?

Comment: it's alright guys, I just added a where clause in the data frame so it filters that out. Thankss